# Match either of Result::Err or an optional field inside of Result::Ok at the same time

Tags: rust, mapping, match

I have a struct that is an API endpoint, so I can't change its structure

```
struct Response {
    error: Option<String>,
    results: Vec<String>,
}
```

If `error` is `Some`, that means it failed server side.

I have a function that returns the struct:

```
fn get_results() -> Result<Response, String> {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

Is it possible to match the `get_results` `Result` error, and the optional `Response.error` in the same `match` branch?

This was my attempt:

```
fn example() {
    let ret = get_results();
    match ret.map(|resp| resp.error.map_or_else(|| Ok(resp.results), |e| Err(e))) {
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Error: {}", &e);
        }
        Ok(results) => {
            //Handle results
        }
    }
}
```

But it fails:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `resp`
  --> src/lib.rs:12:49
   |
12 |     match ret.map(|resp| resp.error.map_or_else(|| Ok(resp.results), |e| Err(e))) {
   |                          ----------             ^^    ---- use occurs due to use in closure
   |                          |                      |
   |                          |                      value used here after move
   |                          value moved here
   |
   = note: move occurs because `resp.error` has type `std::option::Option<std::string::String>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Comment: By the way, you don't need `break;` statements in rust's match statements. Fixed that for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can transform a response into a result like this:

```
match resp.error {
    Some(e) => Err(e),
    None => Ok(resp.results),
}
```

You can flatten a nested result with `and_then`. Put together, it gives this:

```
ret.and_then(|resp| match resp.error {
    Some(e) => Err(e),
    None => Ok(resp.results),
})
```

Answer (score 3):

If the error field is public, you can do something like this:

```rust
match resp {
    Err(s) | Ok(Response { error: Some(s), .. }) => println!("Error: {}", s),
    Ok(Response { error: None, results }) => println!("Responses: {:?}", results)
}
```

This shows how powerful Rust's match statements can be.

[Playground of a simplified example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=16cfd66b0083aa58213e3496c1cf034b)

Answer (score 0):

With the Rust version from 2021 your program **runs now** as is.
Still, I would prefer the [**let-else**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/let_else.html) syntax because it makes the program clearer:

```
fn example() {
    let ret = get_results();
    let Ok(results) = ret else { println!("Error: {}", ret.err().unwrap()); return; };
    // handle results here…
}
```